# String parsing using strtok in C

Tags: c, search, match, strtok, verify

I would like to read from a `.csv` file line by line and then check if the first word of my line matches `string_1`. If it matches, then I would also like to check if the second word matches `string_2`. My `.csv` file contains three fields, namely user, password and type.
Here is my code so far:

```
void verify ( char *user, char *password ) {

    FILE *data;
    char verifyUser[50];

    data = fopen( "password.csv", "r+" );
    while ( fgets(verifyUser, 50, data ) != NULL) {

        char *ptr;
        ptr = strtok(verifyUser, ", ");

        /***What do I do here?***/
    }

    fclose(data);
}
```

In this case, `user` and `password` are `string_1` and `string_2` respectively. Any tips? Can I use `strtok` to split my line into three substrings, and then perform `strcmp` on them? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something along these lines:

```
ptr = strtok(verifyUser, ", ");
if (!ptr || strcmp(ptr, user))
    continue;

/* Okay, so the user matches. */
char *pass = strtok(NULL, ", ");
if (!pass || strcmp(pass, password)) {
    /* Invalid. */
    break;
}
```

Of course this code assumes you already trust the strings `user` and `password` and it's also untested.

Comment: Where should I add my boolean to say that both matches are successful?

Comment: @ cnicutar It wasn't meant to offend you. I unchecked your answer and asked an extra question without even noticing it could be offending. I now understand why you may have found it harmful. Again, please excuse   such behaviour.

Comment: @iHubble No worries. Here, as proof I can easily break my word, you'll want to return 0 instead of the break and return 1 just after the second `if`.

Comment: @iHubble Just ask if anything is unclear, I love helping Canadians.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to sound pedantic but when you open a file, You should add an `if` to test if the file could be opened or not. Something like:

```
if ( ( data = fopen( "password.csv", "r+" ) ) != NULL ){
    printf( "The file couldn't be opened" );
}
else{
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Or at least something to notice if the file couldn't be opened to trace the problem.

Comment: I actually have a condition before executing such function that test if `password.csv` can be opened or not, so that's fine. But thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem you have is that `strtok(verifyUser, ", ")` will split the input line on both commas AND SPACES, so if any of your fields contain spaces (such as a real name), they'll be split into multiple fields.

The usual way to use `strtok` is in a loop:

```
for (token = strtok(inputLine, ","); token; token = strtok(0, ",")) {
    /* do something with token */
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you are not reading it line by Line..you are copying 50 characters into `verifyUser` 

 so it aint gonna work for longer than buffer size `(50)` length.
    fgets(verifyUser, 50, data)

to readline use something like this...

```
getline(data, yourVariable, '\n');
```

and then you can do is..

```
ptr = strtok(yourVariable, ", ");
// now u have to iterate through `ptr` to get all the sub-strings(split-ed using parameter ',')
while(ptr !=NULL){
     if(strcmp(ptr, user)){
         // do stuff here like `break;` etc
     }
}
```

btw it a good practice if u do error checking... like what-if `fopen()` fails (then you should not run rest of the code..)

Comment: -1: fgets reads a single line -- the `50` is the buffer size (so this call won't work if the line is longer that 48 characters, plus trailing newline and NUL).  If you want to read arbitrarily long lines, getline may be a better choice, but fgets is not wrong

Comment: i agree.. fget is not wrong... but as you said it aint gonna work for longer than buffer size length..